# How to give friendly error messages for different kind of exception during SubmitChanges()

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I have a gridview which will have Insert/Delete/Update.
There are two kinds of exception which i am concerning right now is Concurrency and Unique Constraint

Right now i can capture the exceptions by using

```
  private void OnSubmitChangesCompleted(SubmitOperation so)
    {
        if (so.HasError)
        {

            //RadWindow.Alert("Modification is failed because of concurrency issue."+ "\nPlease close the window and reopen it", OnClosed);
            //so.MarkErrorAsHandled();
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Submit Failed: {0}", so.Error.Message));
            so.MarkErrorAsHandled();
        }

    }
```

However, the Message is too unfriendly . And don't clarify whether it is Concurrency exception or Unique constraint exception.

can someone tell me how i can clarify them?I try to use the GetType() to see what kind of exception they have but i both get the exception of DomainOperationException.

Note: for the case of Update , it should be able to capture either Concurrency Exception or Unique constraint exception. For Delete, I think only Concurrency Exception can be thrown. For Insert, only Unique constraint exception can be thrown.

Any help would be appreciated.

I found a similar situation in my case at

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/198896.aspx

but i don't really know how to check something similar as

BananaCannotBeDeleted() in that example because i need to check the Unique or Concurrency which involve the database in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to catch the specific exception server side and throw with you specific message.

For example, catch ConcurrencyException and UniqueConstraintException then throw with your own exception and message.